# Assign member values of struct from pointer

Tags: c, pointers, struct, assign

I have a struct and a function, which returns a pointer to the struct it read:

```
typedef struct cal_t {
    float xm; 
    float ym; 
    float xn; 
    float yn; 
} cal_t;


struct cal_t *lld_tpReadCalibration(void);
```

Somewhere else, I do have an instance of that struct:

```
struct cal_t cal;
```

Now I need to assign tha values of that instance of the struct to the values of the struct I get the pointer returned of. So what I want is that cal.xm is the same value as cal->xm in inside lld_tpReadCalibration(). Symbolicly:

```
struct cal_t cal;

cal = lld_tpReadCalibration();
```

But this dosen't work, of course:

```
error: incompatible types when assigning to type 'volatile struct cal_t' from type 'struct cal_t *'
```

How can I make this work the way I want it?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to dereference the pointer somehow.  You're getting back a pointer from the function, so you're looking for either a `*` operator or `->`, which is of course a synonym for a `*` with .

You define `cal` as a `struct cal_t`, the function returns a pointer to `cal_t`.  so you need to dereference the pointer.

```
cal = *lld_tpReadCalibration();
```

Answer (score 1):

The function return value is struct cal_t *, which is pointer type.

So,you should assign the return value to variable that the type is a struct cal_t *.

For example,

```
struct cal_t *cal_ptr;

cal_ptr = lld_tpReadCalibration();
```